# kubectl - running rollout restart only when configmap changes

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a devops pipeline divided in three steps:

- `kubectl apply -f configmap.yml`
- `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml`
- `kubectl rollout restart deployment/test-service`

I think that when the `configmap.yml` changes the `rollout restart` step is useful. But when only the `deployment.yml` changes, I'm worried that the "extra" `rollout restart` step is not useful and should be avoided.

Should I execute `rollout restart` only when the `configmap.yml` changes or should I don't care about?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer, but it ended up being too long for a comment and I think it's relevant. If you were to apply your manifests using [`kustomize`](https://kustomize.io/) (*aka* `kubectl apply -k`), then you get the following behavior:

- `ConfigMaps` are generated with a content-based hash appended to their name
- Kustomize substitutes the generated name into your `Deployment`
- This means the `Deployment` is only modified when the content of the `ConfigMap` changes, causing an implicit re-deploy of the pods managed by the `Deployment`.

This largely gets you the behavior you want, but it would require some changes to your deployment pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to annotate the deployment's pod with the hash of the configmap. If the content of the configmap changes, the annotation changes and all pods will be rolling updated. If the configmap doesn't change, nothing will happen.

E.g. with helm:

```
annotations:
  checksum/config: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

from [grafana example](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/production/helm/loki/templates/read/deployment-read.yaml).

If you're not using helm you can have a script create the hash in your pipeline.

By that the rollout restart step is not required anymore. Pods will restart always if the configmap and/or the deployment changes. Otherwise nothing happens.